# I am not able to extract Query params from Url in Angular 6

Tags: angular, routes, parameter-passing, angular2-routing, url-routing

i am passing Id as parameter i mu routing path, but while i am extracting prams i am getting error.

i tried to abstract parameter using route.params.subscribe() method.

method where i am passing Id with key name as term

```
onEdit(id:string) {
    console.log(id);   
    this.router.navigate(['../UpdateOrganization',{ term: id }], { relativeTo: this.route }); 
  }
```

My url looks like this :-

http://localhost:4200/#/dashboard/UpdateOrganization;term=MSI3563

Method where i am extracting query parameter from url

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.createFormControls();
    this.createForm();
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      if (params['term']) {
        this.selectedId = params['term'];
      }
    });
    console.log(this.selectedId);
  }
```

I am getting following error message in my console

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

query params usually have a ? before them in url 
so `http://localhost:4200/#/dashboard/UpdateOrganization;term=MSI3563`
should actually be `http://localhost:4200/#/dashboard/UpdateOrganization?term=MSI3563`

I think you are missing queryParams object from there 
 `this.router.navigate(['../UpdateOrganization', { queryParams: { term: id }}], { relativeTo: this.route });`

To read query params you have to do subscribe to queryParams and not params

```
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.param1 = params['term'];
    });
```

In constructor set route to Activated route

`constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}`

Comment: still same issue continues

Comment: can you share your constructor, what is the type of route?

Comment: I have edited my answer to show how constructor should look like

Comment: constructor( private  getOrgList : GetOrganizationListService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute)  {
    
  }

Comment: i have did same as yours

Comment: can you please share from where are you importing ActivatedRoute?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198253/discussion-between-user8351493-and-arpit-aggarwal).

Comment: import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Params } from '@angular/router';

Comment: here it is in same ts where i am extracting queryprameter